# OpenCV - libopencv_calib3d not working

Tags: linux, opencv

I'm newer to Linux,I'm using Ubuntu 12.02.I compiling a program which was done in OpenCV.

The program requirements are:

- OpenCV,
- QT4 Development Libraries,
- V4l2 Development Libraries,
- XTEST Extension Libraries,
- CMake,
- Make

I installed and updated all of that.

The problem was, when I'm try to make it the following error appear:

```
No rule to make target `/libopencv_calib3d.so,needed by "program"
```

But I have `libopencv_calib3d2.3.` I tried to update  it again but, it was already installed ?!

```
77% completed properly
```

Please anyone help me